# How do I use PostgreSQL code snippets?

Tags: postgresql, schema, code-snippets

I'm trying to find a way to copy a schema under a different name. There are [many](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2008-08/msg00014.php) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370614/copy-schema-and-create-new-schema-with-different-name-in-the-same-data-base) to do this. One way is to work on the command line, but it starts getting complicated because of the moving parts ([what user am I running as?](http://dbaspot.com/forums/postgresql/207662-cant-restore-pg_dump-authentication-failed.html)).

If I can simply call a function in the database, that would be perfect. That's when I saw [this page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Clone_schema).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clone_schema(source_schema text, dest_schema text) RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  objeto text;
  buffer text;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || dest_schema ;


    FOR objeto IN
        SELECT table_name::text FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = source_schema
    LOOP        
        buffer := dest_schema || '.' || objeto;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || buffer || ' (LIKE ' || source_schema || '.' || objeto || ' INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING DEFAULTS)';
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || buffer || '(SELECT * FROM ' || source_schema || '.' || objeto || ')';
    END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
Execution is simple:
SELECT clone_schema('old_schema','new_schema');
```

But, I don't know how to install these snippets. **How do I go about that?** It also tells you **"Just remember to create language"** but I don't know what that is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [PSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html) console for this. Either log in and copy paste the script or create a text file and tell PSQL to read it.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I wanted to do it this way was because I'm already connected to the database in my app. I find it a bit smelly to step out of the app to do that task. Also, I piggy back on the logic the app has to connect to the db. For the others, this is how you can create the language needed for what I asked for: http://goo.gl/uPREf

Comment: Create or replace function needs to be run just once, after that you call the function from your app.