# Create view on table which exist in multiple schemas with same name

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create one view (or view in each schema to be used without modifications) on table which exists in multiple schemas with the same name

```
create schema company_1;
create schema company_2;
...
CREATE TABLE company_1.orders
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  amount real,
  paid real,
  CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE company_2.orders
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  amount real,
  paid real,
  CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

....
```

What is correct way of creating view on table orders without specifying schema for every view or specifying current schema?

What I need and failed to get is either

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
public.full_orders AS
SELECT id, amount FROM orders;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
company_1.full_orders AS
-- company_2.full_orders AS
-- company_n.full_orders AS
SELECT id, amount FROM current_schema.orders;
```

Using postgresql 9.2.2

EDIT: The way I went:

```
CREATE VIEW company_1.full_orders AS
SELECT id, amount FROM company_1.orders;
```

On schema copy discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12572088/1695418) I butaly do this

```
FOR src_table IN 
   SELECT table_name 
   FROM information_schema.TABLES 
   WHERE table_schema = source_schema AND table_type = 'VIEW'
LOOP
    SELECT view_definition 
    FROM information_schema.views 
    WHERE table_name = src_table AND table_schema = source_schema INTO q;
    trg_table := target_schema||'.'||src_table;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE VIEW ' || trg_table || ' AS '||replace(q, source_schema, target_schema);
END LOOP;
```

Still looking for better solution...

Comment: Are you wanting to only define a view once but have it work for both tables individually or do you want to combine them i the view?

Comment: @Ilion My goal is to create it once or make it universally reusable. Updated question

Comment: Any chance you can create one schema with one table called orders and create a view that filters out the company_id values other companies shouldn't see?  Basically you have a single table that is now created multiple times every time there's a new company added to the system.  Based on your need to bring them back to together brings me to the thought of why are you doing this in the first place. Is it contract reasons of keeping the data in different schemas?

Comment: @JustBob Reason is quite simple - do not mix data of customers together and leaving out `where company_id = Session.Company.id` out of almost every query. This way there is less possible to show/update wrong users data. All shared data is stored in public schema.

Comment: If  you create a parent table, then create all these other tables as child tables then selecting from the parent table will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe As my understanding selecting from parent will unite all data in single result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do with with a straightforward view.  The view records the underlying table's identity at creation time, so it is not affected by schema settings done later on.

You could do it using a set-returning function using dynamic SQL, and then wrap that into a view.  But I don't think that's a good solution.

I would just create quasi-duplicates for the view, as you have been doing, and enhance my deployment script to keep them all up to date.

Comment: Thank you for function suggestion. Will take that in account.