# How to copy entire schema with tables, data, functions, sequences not using dump/restore?

Tags: postgresql

I need to copy the entire schema into the same database with tables, tables data, functions, sequences, views, material views. I can't use dump/restore method because I haven't got permission on the parent schema. I can't rename it and haven't got access to the console. I tried to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/59176810/9631920 but there are only tables and views.

UPDATE
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51715918/9631920 getting 2 errors when trying to use that function:

1. ERROR: column "max_value" does not exist Perhaps you meant to reference the column "dict_test_value_seq.last_value"
   as I understand it happens because I can no longer get the max_value by selecting from the sequence in new versions of Postgres.
2. When I comment sequence block, I'm getting an error: query string argument of EXECUTE is null, line 177.
   That means that we got null in `EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || buffer || ' AS ' || v_def || ';' ;`

Comment: What do you mean by "*I haven't got permission on the parent schema*"?

Comment: I can't rename it, I can't drop it, because I'm not the owner of that schema

Comment: But to dump it, you don't need to do either of that?

Comment: Btw there are many other answers on the question [Copy schema and create new schema with different name in the same data base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370614/copy-schema-and-create-new-schema-with-different-name-in-the-same-data-base) that should work for you, which don't copy only tables and views.

Comment: Some of the answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51715918/9631920 are using old version of postgres. In this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59176810/9631920 we are copying all table data without sequences, after this, I need manually change every table id type to serial. I thought there can be new solutions for new versions of Postgres

Comment: I need to dump - rename - restore, I tried to restore it on local server, and rename and dump, but I didn't get any views and sequences after restoring that dump

Comment: If [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732283/1048572) is the approach you chose to go with, you should a) leave a comment on the answer asking for an update to recent postgres versions and/or b) ask a specific question about the part of the code that doesn't work any more, including the error message and postgres version you are using.

Comment: And the approach from [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2370719/1048572) should work in either case. Can you show us what exactly you have done (e.g. post the commands you ran and the dump file you got) so that it lost sequences and views?

Comment: Question updated. Tried to make dump - restore using dbeaver, but can't get data from it, only db structure